# How to manipulate trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I would like to write a function that, given an n will exactly add the amount of leaves without degenerating the tree. Something like this:

```
data SimpleT= L | N SimpleT SimpleT deriving Show
```

and addTree defined as:

```
addTree::Int->SimpleT->SimpleT
addTree n (N left right) = something
```

But I can not get it right. The only working thing i've got so far, just adds a (N L L ) on every leaf:

```
 addTree2  L = (N L L)
 addTree2  (N left right)= N (addTree2  left)(addTree2  right)
```

How can I add 'n' properly? With only even numbers for n are allowed.

e.g. adding 2 leaves [image: adding 2 leaves]

Comment: What would it mean to add 3 leaves to an arbitrary tree? Can you draw a picture of it?

Comment: I added a link to a picture. Sorry,it is a bit crappy.

Comment: "without degenerating the tree" -- what does this mean, exactly? Does the tree need to be balanced in some way?

Comment: Any reason the third leaf in your picture is added as a right child instead of a left? It otherwise looks like you want to add leaves in a left-to-right breadth-first manner.

Comment: no reason at all. sorry, the picture is a bit shifted. And by 'degenerated' I meant 'balanced'.

Comment: Your datatype cannot represent the new tree shown in your picture; a node must either be a leaf or an internal node with two children. An `N` node cannot have a single leaf.

Comment: oh, you right. Thank you for the hint. Okay , I changed the picture and just n even number is allowed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need a helper function to figure out which side of the tree is "emptier".

```
height :: SimpleT -> Int
height L = 0
height (N l r) = 1 + max (height l) (height r)
```

Then, it's just a matter of adding 2 leaves at a time to the emptier side (that is, add 2 leaves to the emptier side, then add `n-2` leaves to the resulting tree).

```
-- Warning: partial function, not defined for odd n
addTree :: Int -> SimpleT -> SimpleT
addTree 0 t = t
addTree n L = addTree (n - 2) (N L L)
addTree n (N l r) = addTree (n - 2) (if height l > height r
                                     then (N l (addTree 2 r))
                                     else (N (addTree 2 l) r))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Realy awesome!Just one question. For an better understanding I simplified the addTree function for myself:
`addTree L = (N L L )`


`addTree (N l r) = if (height l > height r) then (N l ( addTree  r) else (N (add l) r)` .
That should add only one ( N L L ) on the emptier side. But it always gives back a parse error on else. Why?

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis in the `then` expression.

Comment: Dang it! Thank you, you  helped me a lot in understanding trees better.

Answer (score 1):

A lazier approach also does not have to keep traversing the tree for quadratic time (still takes suboptimal O(n*log(n)) though, and would give to the right half of your example "first" because it is emptier):

```
size :: SimpleT -> Int
size L = 1
size (N l r) = size l + size r

addTree :: Int -> SimpleT -> SimpleT
addTree 0 t = t
addTree n L = addTree (n-1) (N L L)
addTree n (N l r) = let (u, v) = budget (size l) (size r) n in
  N (addTree u l) (addTree v r)

budget :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
budget l r n = let
  l' = min (n+l) r -- Raise l to r from our budget n
  n' = n+l-l'
  r' = min (n'+r) l' -- Raise r to l from our budget n
  n'' = n'+r-r'
  n''' = div n'' 2
  in (l'-l+n''-n''', r'-r+n''') -- Divide our remaining budget fairly
```

Edit: "That tree is already degenerated - we are supposed not to degenerate it." <- In fact, this gives way to a simpler budgeting solution:

```
budget :: Int -> Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
budget l r n = let (n', m) = divMod n 2
  in (if l>r then swap else id) (n'+m,n')
```

Comment: I don't think this works out quite right. Consider a tree like `N L (N L (N L (N L (N L (N L (N L (N L (N L L))))))))`. `budget` will assign all available nodes to the left subtree without saving any for the right subtree, leaving the tree unbalanced.

Comment: That tree is already degenerated - we are supposed not to degenerate it.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about the given tree being balanced, although that could be a reasonable assumption that was left unstated.